# JavaScript code in iframes in IE9 not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-9

I've a very complete site in ASP.NET which uses iframes. I'm working to change an old control we'd been using to show dialogs to use jQuery UI dialogs. I'm also making sure everything works well in IE9.

The fact is: the script I've in the pages shown in iframes is not working in IE9. Why? Because Object, Array and String are undefined. There may be some others issues, I've seen only this ones.

There is no chance (because a lot of reasons) to stop using iframes on some dialogs. And I'd rather not to use the meta tag to force IE8 Compatibility. Does anyone know any way to fix this ugly bug in IE9?

jQuery code for the iframe in a plugin I've made to config jQuery UI dialog:

```
options.content = $("<iframe>")
    .attr("src", options.intSrcIframe)
    .attr("frameborder", 0)
    .attr("scrolling", options.intIframeScrolling)
    .css("background-color", options.intBgColorIframe)
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("width", "100%");

_this.html(options.content);
```

Comment: How do you know they're undefined?

Comment: Could you provide some sample code on how you instantiate the iframe? Do you load jQuery in the iframe for instance?

Comment: @Šime Vidas: I'm runing the site from visual sudio since this changes are not implemented yet.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Note: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622929%28v=VS.85%29.aspx?ppud=4) there is some documentation from IE9 that may help to understand. Thanks to @Ben Amada for sharing it.

---

After almost a week of going crazy day after day I found it out.

The problem with IE9 is no specifically with the javascript code in the iframes. Not even with the javascript in iframes added by javascript or any library (I have lots of js libraries and plugins that could be screwing IE9).

The problem is when you move the iframe or one ancestor through the DOM. IE9 will excecute the code in the page loaded in the iframe as many times as moves you make. Each time (but the last one) will have Object, String, Array and others undefined (and other bugs too).

Example:

```
var iframe = $("<iframe>").attr("src", "www.example.com").attr("id", "myIframe");
iframe.appendTo("body");
$("#myIframe").appendTo("form:eq(0)");
```

The javascript code in "www.example.com" will be executed once with the error described above and then once with no errors.

With the following code the code will be excecuted just once and correctly:

```
var iframe = $("<iframe>").attr("src", "www.example.com").attr("id", "myIframe");
iframe.appendTo("form:eq(0)");
```

I hope this helps someone to avoid this pain in the ass,

Diego

Comment: Thanks for this analysis. I was about to work on exactly this issue with my website and this will help a lot.

Comment: Thanks, had exactly the same problem. You saved me a lot of frustration.

Comment: Looks like this behavior is from this documented IE9 change: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622929(v=VS.85).aspx?ppud=4.

Comment: Think this answer just saved me from going insane - thanks you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you, @GarethOwen

Answer (score 3):

There is a similar way of achieving this using an existing iframe if you aren't creating a new element.

```
$(function () {
    var iframeSrc = $("#iframeid").attr("src"); // capture target URI
    $("#iframeid").attr("src", "about:blank"); // delay loading until we reposition in the DOM
    $("#iframeid").appendTo("#newparent").attr("src", iframeSrc); // reposition, load iframe by setting src
});
```

IE9 or jquery framework needs to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue, however the iframe is added to the page rather than removed from it. It still appears to have the same problems.

Comment: Is it the source set before of after it is added to the DOM? Once in the DOM is it moved? If yes, try to avoid. Also: should this be an answer?

Comment: The source is never set as the iframe is simply used to be a target of a page submit.

Comment: I can't recall if that happened to me (it was long time ago).