# IE9 throws exceptions when loading scripts in iframe. Why?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, iframe, internet-explorer-9

Precondition:

I have an aspx-page with iframe inside. This iframe points to the url handled by MVC on the same site (it's hybrid site, both standard ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC). The resulting page rendered by MVC contains a lot of scripts references.

Problem:

IE9 throws an exception on every single script it load in iframe. These exceptions are similar to this one:

```
Error: 'Function' is undefined
```

That is, it says that the most basic things every window has is somehow absent. Once you clicked through all of these popups, the page just works as designed!
If I load a URL from `<iframe />` src attribute in the browser directly, everything works as expected.
If I open the page in another browser (I tried Opera, Firefox), everything works as expected -- no errors.

So, what IE9 wants?

Comment: Whatever IE9 wants it will be left wanting, judging by the fact that *we* want *code and pinpointed error messages*.

Comment: "function" doesn't have a capital F in JavaScript. Is this the problem?

Comment: No. [Function Global Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

Comment: @Jon This is IE complaining about a missing 'native' object. Reducing the case is very difficult. I know because I have been there.

Comment: @Diodeus As Eugene says this is not about the function keyword, but about the Function global object. There is a difference. This also makes searching for this topic very hard as google et al are not case sensitive

Comment: I wonder, why there is no my own answer, where described that it was the case of iframe and an UpdatePanel moving it around?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622929%28v=VS.85%29.aspx?ppud=4) about this bug (or feature).

You get these kinds of errors when you move the iframe element around in DOM. In such cases, IE 9 garbage collects the iframe (causing your undefined bug) and reloads it at another position.

In general, you should create the element, set its `src` attribute only *once* and then put it somewhere in the DOM tree *once*. It has nothing to do with the code which runs in the iframe itself.

Comment: +1 - I had this exact problem not five hours ago, and the only thing I changed between "working" and "not working" is a bit of code that moved iframes in the DOM. Removing that bit of code fixed the problem (and I used z-index to produce the same effect).

Comment: similar answer found on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514973/javascript-code-in-iframes-in-ie9-not-working

Comment: I have been on a holiday so couldn't respond sooner, but this does seem related. However in Affected Areas it says this has been changed from IE8 to IE9 but I have seen the missing APIs behavior in IE8 as well... Still congrats with the bounty points!  :)

Comment: If you're using Knockout, move your <iframe> outside of any data-bound elements.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this same situation in the wild. Basic symptoms:

- You load script code in an iframe
- The script code runs early (from the head section or top of body)
- IE complains about some missing native object

I found that it can often be prevented by delaying the execution of the script code until onload or DOMContentLoaded... Not much help I know but this is one of the most difficult IE scripting bugs I have ever encountered. I upped the score of your question, hope it will be found by others as well and we can get a more detailed answer.

Also see this question:
[Error in Internet Explorer 9  (not earlier versions or other browsers) when including jQuery in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528946/error-in-internet-explorer-9-not-earlier-versions-or-other-browsers-when-incl)

Answer (score 2):

Placing the following script block at the very top of the iFrame html <head> seems to resolve the issue in my case. Basically, it forces the iframe to reload, which as some have pointed out, solves the issue. It seems relatively safe, because, without things like 'Object' and 'Date', javascript is essentially useless.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(typeof(Object)==="undefined"){
        window.location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try loading the javascript at the end after complete web page is loaded. I feel the script is executing even before the iframe is completely loaded.

for some suggestion of scripting in IE9 view the given link below
    http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/25/enhanced-scripting-in-ie9-ecmascript-5-support-and-more.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Further investigation revealed that the solution is to add the offending iframe to it's dom location BEFORE setting the 'src' attribute.

Once the 'src' has been set, changing location of the iframe within the DOM stack forces IE9 to garbage collect it.

Once 'src' has been set, iframe can be resized and changed via css positioning, but cannot change the relative location in the DOM stack.

Often times, plugins like dialogs and lightboxes will stuff an iframe with src already set into the dom, then append / prepend or whatever, triggering the GC to take place.

Answer (score 0):

```
function waitForjQuery(){
    if(typeof jQuery!='undefined'){
        //Do yor stuff!
    }
    else{
        setTimeout(function(){
            waitForjQuery();
        },500);
    }
}
waitForjQuery();
```

Comment: How does this even answer the question? It doesn't even seem to apply to the question