# Strange JavaScript errors in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

We have a website (asp.net, C# 3.5, Ajax Control Toolkit 3.5, jQuery 1.3.2) it is working fine in IE8 (also OK in Fire Fox and Google Chrome).

But our client asked us to make it IE9 compatible, when we tested it in IE9 it gives strange errors. Like SCRIPT5009: 'Function' is undefined', Array is undefine, object is undefined, means it says even native javascript object/functions are undefined.

Errors occur on those pages where there are IFrames embedded (good or bad but we can't remove IFrames from those pages).

After doing some R&D people said that IE9 has feature/bug related to IFrames (it was something like that if we change the position of IFrame in DOM after loading the page then IE9 re-initialize the IFrame to prevent memory leaks), we have IFrames inside Collapsible extenders of Ajax Control Toolkit, I don't think that expand/collapse extender changes the position of IFrame in the DOM instead of show/hide. But to overcome this what we did is that we deffered setting the src of IFrames until the page is rendered on client side and DOM is fully ready ( we used the pageLaod client side function of Ajax Control Toolkit) here we set the src of IFrames (don't know this was the right/wrong approach) but it works.

But now most of the time these errors don't occur but they still occur, some time when page is posted back.

Please help us to remove this error.

Comment: What's the site, or relevant code that might be causing the issue?  Have you narrowed it down to anything yet?  If so, please edit your post with the things needed.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier it comes on those pages where we have embedded some pages in IFrames, these pages (which we show in IFrames) are very simple, no complex javascript, if we remove IFrames from the page or visit these pages without IFrame there is no error. Actually there is no code associated with this issue which I can post, IE9 shows that native javascript objects like Array are undefined.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389261/ie9-throws-exceptions-when-loading-scripts-in-iframe-why